# Can mount SMB share using nautilus but not using smbclient

Tags: networking, server, mount, nautilus, samba

I can mount my SMB share using nautilus by simply adding the location `smb://ip`

Here's what happens when I use smbclient on another computer:

```
lz@air:/media$ smbclient -L //192.168.0.3
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter WORKGROUP\lz's password: 
OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    Public          Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 4.5.12-Debian)
Connection to 192.168.0.3 failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
NetBIOS over TCP disabled -- no workgroup available
```

Here's locally, to localhost:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ smbclient -L localhost
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter pi's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    Public          Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 4.5.12-Debian)
Connection to localhost failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED)
NetBIOS over TCP disabled -- no workgroup available
```

Here's my SAMBA configuration:

```
RUN echo '[global]\n\
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536\n\
smb ports = 445\n\
max protocol = SMB2\n\
min receivefile size = 16384\n\
deadtime = 30\n\
os level = 20\n\
map to guest = bad user\n\
printer = bsd\n\
printcap name = /dev/null\n\
load printers = no\n\
create mask = 0644\n\
force create mode = 0644\n\
directory mask = 0755\n\
force directory mode = 0755\n\
browsable = yes\n\
writable = yes\n\
guest account = root\n\
force user = root\n\
force group = root\n\
[Public]\n\
path = /data/share\n\
guest ok = yes\n\
read only = no' > /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

It's worth mentioning that there's no password on my samba

**UPDATE:**

After doing what told in the comment below, I have

```
lz@air:~$ smbclient -L //192.168.0.3
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter WORKGROUP\lz's password: 
OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    Public          Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 4.5.12-Debian)
OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP
```

SHouldn't I see my folders? How should I mount this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] Edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

[2] Place a # sign in front of smb ports = 445 so that it looks like this:

`#smb ports = 445`

This will make it to samba does not read that line and it will default to using ports 445 and 139.

[3] Restart the smbd service:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

> SHouldn't I see my folders?

smbclient -L only lists the shares available on the server - and you have one named Public

> How should I mount this?

```
smbclient //192.168.0.3/Public
```

You will end up at a command prompt: `smb: \>`

Enter  `ls` to get a listing of the contents of Public and `quit` to close the connection.